# jQuery updating class variable values not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, class, oop, variables

I am writing a class in JavaScript for the first time and I am having some trouble writing new data to a class variable. I've been trying all sorts for hours but nothing seems to work!

```
function ClassName(productId) {

    //create variables
    this.productId = productId;
    this.shop = [];
    this.product = [];

  //method that calls for response. On success will return {"status" : "success", "shop" : "someshop.com"}
  this.auth = function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://website.com/api/auth/",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(data) {
              authCallback(data); //use callback to handle response
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log("bad auth");
            }
        });     
    }

  var authCallback = function(r) {
    //using console.log(r) output the response OK
    this.shop = r; //this runs with no errors
  }

}
```

Now, as yo can see in the authCallback method I'm setting `this.shop = r;` but then if i refer back to this variable its still at its default value of `[]` .

```
var class = new ClassName(1);
class.auth();
console.log(class.shop); //this outputs []
```

I've also tried this in the Javascript console writing each line after each stage had been completed(waited for a response from `class.auth()` and output from `authCallback()` before then calling `console.log(class.shop);`

So, what am I doing wrong? Why isn't the variable updating to its new value?

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous. You're calling `console.log()` before the callback has been called.

Comment: @Barmar as I mentioned later down in the question I tried waiting and then writing console.log() in the javascript console... still no luck.

Comment: try `this.authCalback = function(r) { ... }`, `authCallback` should be a member of your class.

Comment: You also have the `this` problem that @Alnitak noted in his answer.

Comment: @KingKing that's insufficient to fix the problem

Comment: @Alnitak I'm not sure, just some suggestion, otherwise I added it as an answer, class in javascript is fairly different/odd compared to other truly object oriented languages.

Comment: @KingKing it's insufficient because the context is set when the function is _invoked_.  It's irrelevant whether the function is actually a member of the "class" or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you just write:

```
authCallback(data);
```

then within `authCallback` you will have the wrong value of `this`, it'll either be `null` or the global object (depending on whether you're in strict mode or not).

Use:

```
success: authCallback.bind(this)
```

to ensure that `this` inside the callback actually represents your object.

You should also note that you cannot access `this.shop` until after the callback has completed.  A more idiomatic implementation using modern jQuery techniques would be this:

```
this.auth = function() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "http://website.com/api/auth/",
        dataType: "jsonp"
    }).done(this.authCallback.bind(this)).fail(function() {
        console.log("bad auth");
    });
};

this.authCallback = function(r) {
    this.shop = r;
    return this;
}
```

followed by:

```
var clazz = new ClassName(1);
clazz.auth().then(function(c) {
   console.log(c.shop);
});
```

Comment: For any people looking at this question in the future with the same sort of problem and the code above isnt working. Where he/she put `.done(authCallback.bind(this))` change it to `.done(this.authCallback.bind(this))` and it works perfectly!

Comment: @user3228693 I've fixed that - it was correct before I made the `.authCallback` a class method.